# Is it possible to make the diamond estimate point a different colour for the subgroups from the overall estimate using forest.meta

Tags: r, graph, colors, graphics, r-forestplot

I am making forest plots of genetic variants effects on an outcome, with the pooled, total estimate being equivalent to a Mendelian Randomisation effect estimate. These forest plots also have subgroups for genetic variants with different characteristics. This means there are pooled estimates for each of the subgroups and one pooled estimate for all the genetic variants together.

The pooled estimates are currently being represented by a diamond shaped point, and all of the pooled estimates are the same colour. Ideally, I would like it that the pooled estimate diamond points for the subgroups are a different colour to the overall estimate diamond point.

I am currently using the forest.meta function (part of the meta software package on R) to make these plots. Here is an example of the code I am currently using.

```
forest.meta(metagenobject, col.square = "black", col.square.lines = "black", xlab = "Causal Effect of genetic variants on outcome", overall = TRUE, overall.hetstat = FALSE, hetstat = FALSE, subgroup = TRUE, leftcols = c("studlab","effect", "ci"), leftlabs = c("SNP", "OR", "(95% CI)"), rightcols = FALSE, smlab = c(" "), digits = 4, xlim = c(0.98,1.02), random = TRUE, print.Q = FALSE, test.subgroup = FALSE, print.subgroup.name = FALSE, text.fixed.w = c("Sub-total","Sub-total","Sub-total"), text.fixed = c("Total"))
```

Is it possible to make the subgroup diamond point estimates a different colour to the overall diamond points estimates using forest.meta ?